# ProcessGetResponseWebException when calling wcf method hosted in azure from visual studio

Tags: wcf, azure, visual-studio-2012

I have a `wcf` web role hosted in azure which has methods to add, delete update etc.  When I step through the code in `vs2012` and call the add method I receive a ProcessGetResponseWebException.

The add method takes a job object as parameter.  This is the only method that's causing a problem.  Any method that doesn't have a job object as a parameter works fine.

The service uses message security with custom username.  This is not the problem as I've removed this and am still having same problem and also the other methods work when security is left in place.

The strange thing is if I install my client as a service and start it it all works fine and there are no problems it only happens when run from visual studio.  I've tried this on another machine using visual studio 2010 and it doesn't work on that either.

When I call the add method from vs and then logon to azure virtual machine I can see that IIS is using 100% of the cpu.

The bindings are correct as I've went through them, all message sizes are set to the max, timeouts are set to 10 mins.  I've even copied the config from the running service that's working just in case and it still doesn't work.

I changed the add method to take a string as a parameter and it works, so it's something with the job object that's passed but can't figure out what and confused as to why it works when installed as service.

I've enabled intellitrace but that doesn't show any exceptions.

Anyone have any suggestions of what I could try next?

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MobileJobs.CloudService.IJobService.AddJob(Job newJob)
   at MobileJobs.CloudService.JobServiceClient.AddJob(Job newJob) in
```

Comment: 1. Can you try if the same service deployed locally works? 2. Can you enable tracing on the server side and see if you get any clue?

Comment: Enabled tracing on the server and also used fiddler to see whats going on but this doesnt help me as they show the same errors.  Will try installing the azure service locally to see if it throws up anything.  This really should be a lot easier to debug.  How can it be that it works when the client service is installed but wont work from vs? Weird.